# Retrieving all the websites hosted on another machine using C#

Tags: c#, iis-7

Currently working on a way to retrieve all the websites hosted on another machine that uses Windows Server, however I can't seem to find any viable way to do so. I tried to use Microsoft.Web.Administration but it always returns null on every object property. This is the code I'm using:

```
        string serverName = "\\nameOfMachine";
        using (ServerManager sm = ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName))
        {
            var all sites = sm.Sites;
        }
```

I'd like to know if there's a way of doing this, or if I'm doing it wrong as all examples I've found were using localhost.

Comment: There are undocumented requirements before you make this function call, http://mvolo.com/connecting-to-iis-70-configuration-remotely-with-microsoftwebadministration/